# Deny use of nameof as parameter of method

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, c#-6.0, nameof

I have this C# function:

```
public void MyFunction(string propertyName)
{
    ....
}
```

The function stores the property name in a database for further use.

I want to prevent the users of this method to use `nameof(MyProperty)` as a parameter, to prevent situations that can occur if the user renames the property in a later version.

Is it possible to specify on a method that it should not be allowed to call with `nameof` as a parameter?

Comment: Why you just  can't validate wheter "propertyName" is valid by comparing it with db value?

Comment: You cannot prevent this. But you can define attributes like `DataPropertyName` at the property and check in your function for the attribute via reflection.

Comment: Yes, you can prevent this but only on a limited basis. If you use Roslyn to inspect all invocations of `MyFunction()` and look at the arguments passed in, you can see whether there's an invocation of `nameof()` or not. If there is, you can throw a compilation error. This will obviously only be possible for code that you have under your control: the analyzer will have to be included in each project that calls `MyFunction()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That sounds interesting.  Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Roslyn SDK at all? If not, your first step to go to is here: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write your own `DiagnosticAnalyzer`, subscribe to `SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression` in the `context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction`. Then check if the method being called is the method in question, and then see if any of the arguments are `nameof` calls. So schematically something like follows:

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
    c =>
    {
        var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)c.Node;
        var symbol = c.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation.Expression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        if (!IsMyMethod(symbol))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (invocation.ArgumentList != null &&
            invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments
                .Select(a => a.Expression)
                .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
                .Any(i => i.Expression.ToString() == "nameof"))
        {
            c.ReportDiagnostic(...);
        }
    },
    SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
```